# Issue With Sharepoint DNS

Tags: dns

I am having a real issue with sharepoint 2010 today.

I have 3 domains in my network. domain a,b,c.

Domain A is the top. 
Domain b has the sharepoint server and is working fine for people in this domain. 
Domain c is where the issue is. This was all just working this morning, but for some reason its not this afternoon. They can ping (by name and IP) the sharepoint server in Domain b, but when they try to go to the url for the sharepoint site nothing comes up.

I can still set privileges on the users in Domain C from Domain B sharepoint administration but they still cannot see it.

Comment: By 'domain' are you referring to the domain name as in 'xyz.domain1.com' or are these Active Directory Domains?

Comment: separate domains, domaina.com, domainb.com, domainc.com

Comment: Better off asking in http://serverfault.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the barracuda web filter was the issue. You need to add a static route in it to make it talk http traffic across two domains. I hate that thing. It causes so many issues and has so many limitations.